# how to setup a proper callback to retrieve data

Tags: c++

I have the following situation, I have two classes.  I pass an instance of class 1 to an instance of class two through a callback function.  Ultimately the goal is to connect to something (say sql server) and retrieve some datasets maybe every x number of minutes.  How would I amend the below so that after passing an object of class 1 to the object of class 2, I can somehow get the object 1 to do all the work.  Essentially I need the implementation of connecting to SQl and getting data to be in the work() function of class foo.  and more importantly how do I relay the result set back to the user in main();

Does that make sense at all? Is the correct?  The ultimate goal is to latch onto a sql server and grab a dataset every 5 minutes and generate some statistics to be returned to the user, should this be modified at all? Should the connection be handled by the foo class or the bar class

```
class foo{
    public:
        void work(int id, &result){}
};


class bar{
    private:
        foo* foo_
    public:
        void callback(foo* tempfoo){
            foo_ = tempfoo;
        }
        void work();
};

int main(){
    foo send;
    bar receive;
    receive.callback(&send);

    //do a bunch of stuff with the receive object to get the result

    bar.work(//some parameters that are needed to generate the result);
}
```

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Callback is implemented by passing a function pointer to a function and then invoking the passed in function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The class that wants to call a callback should take a function pointer and then call that pointer when appropriate (when work is done).

There are a couple of options as to how exactly to pass a function pointer. You could use Lambda (as in the example code below), or you could use std::bind with a member function.

Example below:

```
class foo(){
public:
    foo()
    ~foo()
    work(int id, &result){
        //do work
        //call callback with some params
        callback(PARAMS);
    }

    void setCallback(std::function<void(PARAMETERS)> cb){
        callback = cb;
    }

private:
    std::function<void(PARAMETERS)> callback = nullptr;
}

class bar(){
private:
    foo* foo_
public:
    bar()
    ~bar()
    work();
}

int main(){
     foo send;
     bar receive;
     receive.setCallback([](PARAMETERS){
         //your callback code in lambda
         //send and receive are not captured here
         //if you wish to capture send and receive
         //you should somehow maintain their existence in memory
         //until the callback is called, otherwise you'll get bad access error
         //due to those guys already destroyed
         //to capture send and receive you should put them into [] of lambda declaration.
         //Append & if you want to capture by reference.
    }); 
    receive.work(//some parameters that are needed to generate the result);
}
```